# How to create a shortcut to Sounds>Playback>Speakers>Properties>Enhancements?

Tags: audio, shortcuts, control-panel

I have found this piece of code

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,0
```

which works in both CMD and windows RUN and gets me to the Sounds>Playback, the rest of the code below seems not to be doing anything although people who posted it online claimed it worked for them, any ideas?

```
WinWait,Sound
Send,{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}
Send,{Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
```

It would be nice to run it in a shortcut, but batch file will suffice as long as it works.

[image]

Comment: The code posted looks like an AutoHotKey script ... have you tried it?

Comment: Someone suggested using voicemeeter, a virtual soundboard, to get the same effect as the "listen to device" option. and it can toggle with a hotkey too

https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/

Answer (score 1):

try this code in AutoHotKey app

```
run rundll32.exe shell32.dll`, Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl`,`, 0
WinWait, ahk_class #32770       
Send, {Down 2} ;<--Adjust with your speaker line number from top-->
Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
WinWait, ahk_class #32770
Sleep, 50
Send, ^{Tab}^{Tab}
Send, {Down 3}{Tab}
```